# Use view in report

Tags: sql-server, erp, dynamics-nav, navision

I have created a view in SQL Server. I'd like to use this view to create a report in Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009. Is this possible and if so, how can I use the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible but you need a new navision table and change the property 'LinkedObject' to Yes.

Further, you need to name the table exactly like the view.

Here are some further hints.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339076.aspx

You then can use that table like any other table in nav with some limitations..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another good tutorial regarding your question:

http://dynamicsuser.net/blogs/waldo/archive/2008/11/08/how-to-display-an-sql-server-view-in-microsoft-dynamics-nav.aspx